# Special kind of motivation for number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question, recreational-mathematics, motivation

This is bit different for other motivation related questions, so I am defining it clearly. First of all,

> I am asking motivation for starting to do (elementary/beginning) number theory - which includes very basic topics like congruences, divisibility, linear diophantine equations and theorems of Fermat and Wilson.

But, here's what I mean by motivation:

> Give me an example of curious and semi-concrete stuff, which mechanism is buried deep inside those mathematics.

For example:

> As a motivation for learning ordinals and set theory, I found working on the hydra game (that you can always kill the hydra !) a very useful motivation. For doing group theory, doing tricks on Rubik's cube was a very interesting motivation.

Comment: (This is the second and last question in a series. The first one is : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211276/special-kind-of-motivation-for-algebra )

Comment: Cryptography:  Take 2  primes $p,q.$ Take $ab=pq-p-q+2$.Take a block of text, stored  as a number $x<pq,$ with a few extra bits to ensure $\gcd (x,pq)=1. $  (Q: How?) Calculate $y=x^a$ modulo $ pq.$  (Q: How?).Send $y.$ The recipient calculates  $y^b$ mod $pq=x$.    Show the superiority of this over simple substitution codes, but the math Q is : Why does this work?

Comment: There is a math. education  exchange or overflow site for teachers

Comment: Some good stuff here: http://listverse.com/2013/05/15/10-fun-examples-of-recreational-number-theory/